# Is there a way to `fgrep` with the "and" of all the passed in patterns instead of the "or"?

Tags: grep

I want to do a search in a log file like this:

/logs/loggy.log:

```
INFO:  cats are people
DEBUG: one doth fig're and therefore one doth be
INFO:  cookies made via the catapultation of figs at an acceleration of 1 m/s^2.
INFO:  informative information about my information systems
```

I want just the 3rd line. So I command:

```
grep 'cat.*fig' /logs/loggy.log
```

But it's a large file! Let's make it faster

```
grep -F -e cat -e fig /logs/loggy.log
```

0ops. Now I'm getting back all the lines because it now matches for either 'cat' or 'fig'. I want it to match only lines containing bolth. Is there a way to do this without going back into regular expressions land?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agrep` if it is available in your distro repos, which nativelly provides `and` operation:

```
$ agrep 'cat;fig' file1
```

Or you can use any of the following alternatives:

```
$ grep 'cat' file1 |grep 'fig'
$ awk '/cat/ && /fig/' file1
```

In all above cases the result is:

```
INFO:  cookies made via the catapultation of figs at an acceleration of 1 m/s^2.
```

Comment: Very good.  One minor point:  the OP said speed was important.  When regex is not required, grep's `-F` option, as in the OP's example, can provides substantial speed up.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks. Since `grep -F 'cat'` matches `cats`, `catapultation` as well as `application` , the word "when regex is not required, grep's -F option" is a big conversation...

Comment: It didn't occur to me to do `grep -F cat file1 | grep -F fig`. I think this is what i was looking for, or close enough.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou It's not clear to me what point you are driving at.  For the term `cat`, grep yields the same matches with or without `-F`.  It's just that, with `-F`, it is faster.